# Catch Application Exceptions in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

Is there anyway to catch expections that is thrown by anywhere in the code? I would like to catch exceptions and handle them in a similar manner rather than writing try catch blocks for each functionality.

Comment: This is not something you want to do instead of handling locally but in addtion to. See may answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Windows Forms applications, when an exception is thrown anywhere in the application (on the main thread or during asynchronous calls), you can catch it by registering for the ThreadException event on the Application. In this way you can treat all the exceptions in the same way.

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod);

private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
    //Exception handling...
}
```

Comment: Just in case it might help somebody. Please be sure to register to the event handler (Application.ThreadException += ...) before running the application (Application.Run(...);). Otherwise, it will not work (as it happened to me)

Comment: This answers the question, but the link Brian Dishaw has in his answer is very comprehensive, and has all (if not most) use cases covered.  The only thing that's not useful in a production app would be the method returning a Dialog with the error message.  A real production app would send to the Event Log, instead of having a Dialog pop up in your application.

Answer (score 24):

I think this is a close as you can get to what you are looking for within a win form application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905.aspx

```
// Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException);

// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through
// our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Without doing all of these steps you run the risk of having some exceptions get unhandled.

Comment: This is my main loop (my app starts hidden, with a statusbar icon). With your code, I still need to wrap `new Form1();Application.Run();` inside a try/catch...

Answer (score 19):

The obvious answer is to put an exception handler at the top of your execution chain.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    try
    {
        Application.Run(new YourTopLevelForm());
    }
    catch
    {
        //Some last resort handler unware of the context of the actual exception
    }
}
```

This will catch any exception that occurs on your main GUI thread. If you also want to globally catch exceptions that occur on all threads you can subscribe to the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event and handle there.

```
Application.ThreadException +=
    new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod)
private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(
                                              object sender,
                                              ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
    //Exception handling...
}
```

*Code copied from [Charith J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291933/catch-exceptions-in-a-windows-forms-application/6291982#6291982)*

Now on to the advice ...

These options should only be used as a last resort, say, if you want to suppress accidentally uncaught exceptions from presentation to the user. You should be catching sooner whenever possible, when you know somthing about the context of the exception. Even better, you may be able to do something about the problem.

Structured exception handling might seem like an unecessary overhead which you can work around with a catch all but, it exists because this is not the case. What is more, this work should be done as the code is written, when the developer has the logic fresh in thier mind. Do not be lazy and leave this work for later or for some more profressional developer to pick up.

Apologies if you already know and do this.

Comment: @Downvoter, any critisicm gratefully recieved, I'm here to learn.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)